# how to export excel sheet save as image by phpexcel

Tags: php, excel

I have an Excel sheet and want to export it to save as image by phpexcel, how can I do?
My Excel sheet like this:phptest.xlsx

[image]

I want to export this sheet as an image：for example, saving as image
, got a phptest.png

[image]

Comment: And you want to do this using PHP?

Comment: yes,how can i do it

Comment: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: do this have api to export sheet as image?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, you should have a minimum content as your research. You are not showing any effort, just asking for a solution.